# How to stop a loop when the end of a word document is found?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that validates an Active Document word by word. If a word in Active Document is listed in a "Bible of Terms", then the macro adds a comment to the Active Document with a suggestion to replace that word with a better one.  Example: Term= "He is ", Suggestion= "He's ". The Bible  contains a table with 600 terms, one term per row. Column 1=term, Column 2= suggestion). My code loops through 600 terms in the Bible. This is inefficient because if the document I'm validating only has one word, the loop still runs 600 times. How can I stop the code when the document I'm validating reaches its end?  Or don't even run the process if the document has nothing.

```
Dim BibleCounter as Integer
Dim MaxWordsInBible as Integer
MaxWordsToValidate = (ActiveDocument.Words.Count - 1)  'Count words in doc to validate
MaxWordsInBible = Documents(MatrixDocNum).Tables(1).Rows.Count  'Count rows in bible
For BibleCounter = 2 To MaxWordsInBible  'Currently loops 600 times 
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.range  'Activedocument I'm validating against Bible 
   With findRange.Find
                     .Text = BibleFile.Tables(1).Rows(BibleCounter).Cells(1).range.Text                       
                     .MatchWholeWord = False
                     .Wrap = wdFindStop  'stops find at the end of the document
'Loop to find the suggestion to replace a word in the activedocument with a term in the Bible
                     Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                        suggestion =  BibleFile.Tables(1).Rows(BibleCounter).Cells(2).range.Text
                        ActiveDocument.Comments.Add findRange, Text:=suggestion
                        findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd    'to avoid endless loop
                     Loop   'do while
   End With 'findRange.Find
Next BibleCounter
```

Comment: There really isn’t a simple answer to this. You could take the count of words in the document to be checked and, if it is very low, reverse the logic of your code and use the words in the document to search your bible, though as you appear to be replacing phrases rather than words this approach is unlikely to work for you.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Based on your suggestion, I will take the count of words in the document and compare to the count of terms in the bible file. Depending on which is less, I will base the code use the document or the bible file as a base. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expedite things a bit by disabling ScreenUpdating. The code could also be improved somewhat, especially regarding how you retrieve the table text:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim BibleFile As Document, Tbl As Table
Set BibleFile = "some document"
Set Tbl = BibleFile.Tables(1)
For BibleCounter = 2 To Tbl.Rows.Count  'Currently loops 600 times
  With ActiveDocument.Range  'Activedocument I'm validating against Bible
    With .Find
      .Text = Split(Tbl.Cell(BibleCounter, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop  'stops find at the end of the document
      'Loop to find the suggestion to replace a word in the activedocument with a term in the Bible
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found = True
      .Comments.Add Range:=.Duplicate, Text:=Split(Tbl.Cell(BibleCounter, 2).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd    'to avoid endless loop
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
   End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Looping through the whole table isn't likely to add a lot of time for expressions that aren't found - it's processing all the found ones that is likely to consume most of the time.

Of course, if the document has only a few words, you should consider reversing the process and using that document as the source to check against your BibleFile.

Comment: The Application.ScreenUpdating = False and True save time. Based on your comments, I will reverse my code to use the document as the source to check against the BibleFile. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there are multiple solutions.  My solution is to use inrange (pesudocode);

```
dim searchRange as Range = activeDocument.content
Dim findRange as range = searchRange.duplicate 

findRange.find.execute

Do

     If findRange.find.found andalso findRange.inrange(searchRange) then

           ‘ do processing

       End if

       findrange.collapse (end)
 
       findRange.find.execute
  
While  findrange.find.found
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking. My understanding is that the OP wants the loop to run less than 600 times in circumstances that aren't clearly stated.

Comment: you are right Timothy. So the original question is about checking 600 terms in a document needs 600 cycles and this may be inefficient if the document has only a few words. In the end the logic still is 'for each word in 1 set, check if it exists in the other'. the Bible set is 600 (given) but the document may 10 words or 1000 words (or whatever). I'm not sure that there is a simple answer

Comment: @Boeryepes That's correct, if the document has 3 words, it still has to check each word against the 600 terms in the bible file.

Comment: you could consider a variable logic: if the document has a few words, then run each word against the 600 terms instead of 600 times a bible term against the document. E.g. if the document has 10 words then do 10x600 instead of 600x10. In all this I presume you have already loaded the 600 terms in memory.